# Backup database use crontab with date function

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I can use this command

```
mysqldump -u"root"  myDB| gzip > mydb_`date +%d-%m-%Y`.sql.gz
```

but when run in crontab

```
* * * * * mysqldump -u"root"  myDB| gzip > mydb_`date +%d-%m-%Y`.sql.gz
```

( this error cause by function date, when i remove it , crontab run good )

on ubuntu, it happen this error in log file.

```
ubuntu CRON[xxxx] (user) CMD(mysqldump -u"root"  myDB| gzip > mydb_`date+)
ubuntu CRON[xxxx] (CRON) error ( grandchild #5353 failed with exit status 2)
ubuntu CRON[xxxx] (CRON) info (no MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: Your crontab is not the same command you are running from the command line.  You omitted the `date +%d-%m-%Y`  (noting the lack of backtics) which are what make that actually work, as the backtics execute and return the result of the date .... function.

Comment: it is same but i can't write out with stackoverflow .

Comment: Yes you can.  Use backticks to format part of a line as code; indent by 4 or more spaces to format one or more lines as code.  Select the range of text and click the `{}` icon to do this automatically.  Or you can escape a backtick with a backslash: `\``.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`%` signs in a crontab command are converted to newlines, and all data after the first `%` is sent to the command's stdin.  Replace each `%` with `\%`.

(And you only had 4 time fields: `* * * *`; you need 5 (you later fixed the question).)

Comment: i fixed question is * * * * *

Answer (score 0):

From the `man 5 crontab`:

> The ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
>   run.
>
> The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or %
>   character, will be executed by  /bin/sh  or  by the  shell  specified 
>   in  the SHELL variable of the crontab file.
>
> Percent-signs (%) in the
>   command, unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into
>   newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the
>   command as standard input. There is no way to split a single command
>   line onto multiple lines, like the shell's trailing "\".